# Add feedback and score values (answer key area) to Google form from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I currently am using a script that will automate the creation of a form from data is a Google sheet. Now that Google has released the "quiz" form template, I want to add feedback and scores to the form as well through the same sheet. I've looked through other questions with no answer. In my research there is no method within the Form class.

Please help, I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you can do with Google Form Quizzes is found in [Create a quiz with Google Forms](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287?hl=en)

And here's the information about feedbacks:

> If you collect email addresses, you can assign points and leave
>   feedback on individual responses to send later. After you grade a
>   response, be sure to save your changes.

**Grade individual responses**

1. Open a form in Google Forms.
2. At the top, click RESPONSES.
3. Click INDIVIDUAL.
4. To move between responses, click Previous Previous or Next Next.
5. Find the question you want to grade.
6. In the top right, enter how many points the response earned.
7. Under the answer, click Add individual feedback.
8. Enter your feedback and click SAVE.
9. To save your changes, click SAVE.
10. When you’re ready, you can [email scores to individuals](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287#release_scores).

Comment: I'm very familiar with how to use forms. This question is related too writing scripts and automatically pulling data out of a Google sheet and putting it into a form template. I have 700 questions with feedback and score values in a Google sheet and I want to automate this. My script will import the questions but not the feedback or score to the answer key.